# Flutter: Dart analysis doesn't work after using package in dev_dependencies

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, dart-packages

Normally, dart analysis will notice every time something is not correctly like missing const.
[image]

But, dart analysis doesn't work after I use the flutter_native_splash or the flutter_native_splash package used in dev_dependencies. It shows only that thing.
[image]

I notice that after cloning a project. Before using these packages in the dev_dependencies, I saw many notices from dart analysis.

What going on? How to use these packages with dart analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the `flutter_lints: ^...` in `dev_dependencies:`